# Lazy Loader / Infinite Scroll with Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, lazy-loading

I am attempting to create an infinite scroll similar to twitter/facebook/google docs. I've looked into many plugins and tutorials but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Seems that everything I looked at loads another page via ajax rather than pulling only a portion of the content from the database.

```
        <div class="question">
            {% if the_question %}
              <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="votecounter">
                        <span class="score" id="linkscore{{ question_id }}"
                        title="after {{ score.num_votes|default:0 }} vote{{ score.num_votes|default:0|pluralize }}">
                        {{ score.score|default:0 }}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="votearrowdiv">
                        <form class="linkvote" id="linkup{{ question.id }}" action="/home/{{ question.id }}/{% if vote and vote.is_upvote %}clear{% else %}up{% endif %}/vote/" method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="image" id="linkuparrow{{ question.id }}" class="{% if vote and vote.is_upvote %}uparrowBlue{% else %}uparrow{% endif %}" value=""></input>
                        </form>
                        <form class="linkvote" id="linkdown{{ question.id  }}" action="/home/{{ question.id }}/{% if vote and vote.is_downvote %}clear{% else %}down{% endif %}/vote/" method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="image" id="linkdownarrow{{ question.id  }}" class="{% if vote and vote.is_downvote %}downarrowBlue{% else %}downarrow{% endif %}" value=""></input>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                        <div class="actualQuestion">
                        <a href="/home/{{ content.id }}/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a>
                        </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If loading another page (actually a portion of another page) via ajax isn't what you want, then what is?  Normally fetching a slice of content at a time via ajax is considered "pulling only a portion of the content from the database".  Another option would be to fetch a json response and inflate a template with that information client-side, but that's ajax too.  Which part of the process is objectionable?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with jQuery endless

https://github.com/fredwu/jquery-endless-scroll